# Redux store not being updated after dispatching action

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Hi all I am new to react and have been working on a project the last week I have been trying to build this login for django rest framework using react and redux toolkit.

As I understand it, redux action creators create actions which then get dispatched to reducers for changing global state. If this is the case, why is my action creator for login not saving the access and refresh tokens to the store!!!???!!?!?!?!??!

Below is my code.

--Login.js
---Where most of the login logic is happeneing and the action creator for login is being used.

```
import { useState } from "react"
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from "react-redux"
import {login} from '../features/auth/authSlice'
import axios from "axios"
const Login = () => {
    const userToken = useSelector((state)=>state.auth)
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    

    const authenticate = async ()=>{
        // const resp = await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/auth/login', {formData})
        const resp = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/auth/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({username:username, password:password})
        })
        const data = await resp.json()
        console.log(data);
        dispatch(login({
            accessToken: data.access,
            refreshToken: data.refresh
        }))
        return data
        
    }
    

    const handleSubmit = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(username, password);
        // authenticate().then((data)=>{ }) 
        authenticate()
        setTimeout(()=>{
            console.log(userToken);
            
        }, 3000)
        console.log(userToken);
        
    }
    return ( 
        <div>
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <div className="Auth-form-container">
        <form className='Auth-form' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className="Auth-form-content">
                <h2 className='Auth-form-title'>Login SSl Test</h2>
                <div className="form-group mt-3">
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control mt-1"
                    placeholder="Enter username"
                    value={username}
                    onChange={(e)=>setUsername(e.target.value)}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group mt-3">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input
                    type="password"
                    className="form-control mt-1"
                    placeholder="Enter password"
                    value={password}
                    onChange={(e)=>setPassword(e.target.value)}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="d-grid gap-2 mt-3">
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
                    Submit
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    );
}
 
export default Login;
```

--AuthSlice.js
---My redux toolkit slice for authentication

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
    accessToken: null,
    refreshToken: null
}


const authSlice = createSlice({
    name:'auth',
    initialState,
    reducers:{
        login:(state, action)=>{            
            state.accessToken = action.payload.accessToken
            state.refreshToken = action.payload.refreshToken
        },
        logout:(state, action)=>{
            state.accessToken = ''
            state.refreshToken = ''
        }
    }
});

export const {login, logout} = authSlice.actions
export default authSlice.reducer
```

Thank you in advance, I have rly been banging my head against this one. Any help is appreciated, but we like real answers, lol.

Im rly lost here everything looks good to me, just don't know why when I try to access the store state after login in the tokens are not there

Comment: Try removing `payload` from reducer,  
            `state.accessToken = action.accessToken`
            `state.refreshToken = action.refreshToken`

Comment: @AbhishekSingh this is Redux Toolkit, `payload` is correct.

Comment: @jamesc if you look at it in Redux Devtools, do you see the action there?

Answer (score 0):

Your state probably changes. The problem is the way you access `userToken`. You are accessing a stale closure variable here - the `userToken` from last render. If you put a `console.log(userToken)` into your component itself you will see that the component rerenders and that after that rerender, there is a new variable called `userToken` that has the right value. It's just that old variable from last render that you are interacting with there that will never change.

Comment: So how do i fix that?

Comment: It really depends on what you actually want to do with that token. If you really only need it at next render, you're already set and were just logging in the wrong position. If you immediately need it, you are already returning it from `authenticate`, and you already have commented-out code to immediately access that after `authenticate` finished successfuly. And your base assumption of "your state is not updating" was probably just a non-problem.

Comment: Ok but after I run authenticate and I check the userToken variable isnt null where do I need to have the log to see the correct state??

Comment: The commented out code I think your talking about
```
        // authenticate().then((data)=>{ }) 
```
doesnt show me the right variable

Comment: Ive console.loged userToken everywhere in my componet and it still gives me accessToken as null

Comment: `authenticate().then((data)=>{ console.log(data.access) })` should totally give you that access token. If that's not the case, you never got the data from `fetch` in the first place - you might have a CORS problem then, which would mean you need to change your server.